# SNR definition in SIMO system

Tags: communication, digital-communications, transmission, snr

Consider a SIMO (1 transmitter - several receivers) system in which The receiver antennas are used to obtain space diversity and we have a **multipath** fading channel between transmitter and each receiver.

Obviously, the SNR for different antennas are different (even if the AWN power for all antennas be the same) as the channel for different antennas are different.

The output of the antennas are combined in a method to obtain an estimation of transmitted signal, however I wonder how do you formulate the SNR in this system? Indeed if I want to draw the figure of merit for my system, then I must say ... FER is obtained at ? SNR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to simulate a SIMO system, you must treat each channel fairly, it means that **in average** the channels' power must be the same, and to have a correct comparison between your results and others, you must set this **average** power to be equal to 1. So Although instantaneous SNRs for different receivers are different, but **in average** they are equal.